# in react, what functionality goes into componentDidMount versus render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

it appears that `componentDidMount()` is called after `render()`.

since `render` had a callback argument, is `componentDidMount()` really needed?

philosophically, is it different coding that supposed to go into each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`render()` will be called more than once, normally, during the lifecycle of a component, while `componentDidMount()` will be called only once. They have different meaning. Just quote the official doc:

> The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify
>   component state, it returns the same result each time it's invoked,
>   and it does not read from or write to the DOM or otherwise interact
>   with the browser (e.g., by using setTimeout). If you need to interact
>   with the browser, perform your work in componentDidMount() or the
>   other lifecycle methods instead. Keeping render() pure makes server
>   rendering more practical and makes components easier to think about.

Comment: so the idea is that changes in state or props will cause a new render(), but not a new componentDidMount() - is this correct?

Comment: @ccyoung Yes. As long as the component is mounted, the `componentDidMount()` will not be executed any more. Unless you unmount it by using `React.unmountComponentAtNode()`, or rendering a different class of component `React.render(<AnotherComponent />, NodeCurrentlyMountedAt)`, in which case the `componentDidMount` of `AnotherComponent` will run after its first  `render()`

Comment: There are other methods you can use if you want something done before each render.